# How to split a complicated angular interface

Tags: angularjs, architecture, controller, view, states

I have an interface in angularJS with 3 table (on for adding lines) other for displaying and another for displaying and inserting data.I also have inputs and attachments.The interface contains so much data.I work with concept of states.I am new to angular so i don't have a clear idea on how to split this interface.Should i have one controller or multiple controller?!! At the end the user should submit the hole form.Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should have 1 component with 3 components inside like :

```
<div>
    <table1></table1>
    <table2></table2>
    <table3></table3>

    <button>SUBMIT</button>
</div>
```

Depending how your data is structured, you should inject a service in the parent component and then pass the data as **(input)** for each component or use the service to get the data from components.

Also components will set/get data with that service, so the service should keep the state of these 3 components/data and can submit data from the parent component.

There are no controllers in Angular anymore.

Comment: i don't use ang2 ;) i'm working with a framework who is based on ang1

Comment: oh, I thought so, feel bad for you, angular2 is a lot better :)  The correct naming now is : the old version angular1 is angularJS and the the new version Angular2,4,5..etc is just Angular

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, since your model can be seen as the whole form data structure I think that you have to use **one controller** and one service for the backend communication.

In order to keep your UI cleaner you should have one **partial** for each table. With partial I mean an html "sub-view" that you will load with `ng-include` into your main view.

Since each partial inherites the **parent scope**, you will find all your scope data in each partial.

Hope this could help you